# Bash function not returning value properly

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I don't know what is wrong with my function; it is not returning value properly.

```
function validate_directory_isempty     {
    retval=""

    NumOfFiles=`ls -l $input | egrep -c "^-"`

    if [ "$NumOfFiles" == "0" ];then
            retval=true

    else
            retval=false

    fi
    echo $retval
}


retval=$(validate_directory_isempty /opt/InstallationManager)
echo "retval : " $retval
if [ "$retval" == "true" ]; then
        echo ""
        echo "Installing Installation Manager"

#       Install_IM

else
        echo ""
        echo "DIRECTORY is not empty. Please make sure install location $DIRECTORY is empty before installing PRODUCT"

fi
```

Comment: Please remember to indent your code in a more orthodox manner.  Your code was unreadable at first.  Highlight your code and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it 4 spaces, but the body of your function shouldn't be 30-odd spaces indented.

Comment: The variable `input` is not defined in `validate_directory_isempty`

Comment: As @linuxfan points out, `$input` is not defined in the function. The arguments to the function are in `$1` etc; you probably want to replace `$input` with `"$@"`.  Also note that the `function` notation is not preferred; POSIX would use `validate_directory_isempty() { ...code as fixed... }`.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to have a function return true or false is to use the `return` keyword. A return value of 0 means success, a non-zero value means failure. Also note that a function will return with a status of the last command executed if `return` is not present.

I would write your function like this

```
is_dir_empty() {
    shopt -s nullglob
    local -a files=( "$1"/* )
    (( ${#files[@]} == 0 ))
}

directory=/opt/InstallManager
if is_dir_empty "$directory"; then
    echo "$directory" is empty
fi
```

The first line sets a shell option that pattern matching no files expands to null instead of the pattern itself as a string.

The second line fills an array with the filenames in the given directory.

The last line tests the number of elements in the array. If zero entries, return success else return failure.

Answer (score 0):

i just replaced my script as below and it worked

removed the below commands
retval=$(validate_directory_isempty /opt/InstallationManager)
echo "retval : " $retval

added
input=/opt/InstallationManager
validate_directory_isempty

and it worked.

Thanks again for your valuable inputs